# Minimize the sum of Type I and Type II errors

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Given $X_1,\dots,X_n$ a simple random sample with normal variables ($\mu, \sigma^2$). We assume $\mu$ is unknown but $\sigma$ is known.

Now consider the hypothesis
$ 
 \begin{cases}
 H_0: & \mu=\mu_0 \\
 H_1: & \mu=\mu_1 > \mu_0
 \end{cases}
 $

Determine the critical region $R$ in order to minimize the risk $P_{H_0}(R)+P_{H_1}(R^c)$.

I'm not sure how to start this problem, in particular due to the fact that I'm dealing with $n$ samples here. I believe the test statistic I have to apply here is $z=\displaystyle\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{(\sigma/\sqrt{n})}$, but I'm not sure how the application of it follows.

**EDIT**

Alright, let's consider the following: using the error function above I have that the error function with mean 0 and variance $\sigma $ is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{\alpha/(\sigma\sqrt{2})} e^{-t^2}dt$.

This error gives the probability of falling in $(-\alpha,\alpha)$ but I am interested in the rejection region, this is $(-\infty, \alpha)\cup(\alpha, +\infty)$. Therefore, I think I should consider the complementary error function

$$
\operatorname{erfc}(\alpha) = 1-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{\alpha/(\sigma\sqrt{2})} e^{-t^2} \, dt = \frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{\alpha/(\sigma\sqrt{2})}^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt
$$

Now I could derive and get that $\frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{erfc}(\sigma) = - \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\alpha^2/(2\sigma^2)}$. I should set it to $0$ and find $\alpha$, to "solve" the problem.

There are three issues here:
(1) $e^{-\alpha^2/(2\sigma^2)}$ will never be zero for any $\alpha$.

(2) I didn't get involved the hypothesis testing.

(3) It is not clear what the $\sigma$ in the error function is. The wikipedia entry linked above says that error generally have mean zero, but it is possible for the error to have a variance. Is the $\sigma$ in the normal distribution the very same $\sigma$ in the error function?

Comment: $\mu$ is known? Maybe $\sigma^2$ is known.

Comment: You introduce the $X_i$ and then they are not mentioned in the rest of the problem description.  Is there a relationship between the $X_i$ and any of $\mu$, $\mu_0$, or $\mu_1$?  (This *sounds* like a problem in using the sample variance to estimate the population variance, but that would tie $\mu_0$ or $\mu_1$ to the $X_i$.  As currently written, $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$ are complete unspecified constants, so it's a little odd to assert that one is greater than the other.)

Comment: For null hypothesis μ0= μ It should be σ2. which is known and μ unknown

Comment: And your test statistic is appropriate for the null hypothesis

Comment: @EricTowers From what I understand, $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are samples of $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and $X_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma^2_i)$.

Comment: @SutirthaDatta But how the test helps me to determine $P_{H_0}(R)$?

Comment: How does it make sense to talk about a null hypothesis about the value of $\mu$ when you said $\mu$ is known? I have to suspect you meant $\sigma^2$ is known and $\mu$ is not.

Comment: @Cure : $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are not samples; they are observations in a sample.

Comment: @MichaelHardy. I took it to mean that a particular hypothetical value of $\mu$ is firmly in mind. Otherwise, the structure with $H_0$ and $H_1$ makes no sense. A regrettably pervasive bit of confusion. Also, the use of $s$ suggests $\sigma$ is not known, as is almost always the case. If I'm wrong, I hope your Comment prompts a clarification from OP.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm starting to believe it might have been a typo, but it is how the problem was stated.

If you take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJZpx7Mdde4 3:50 you can see the uploader calculated the probabilty of a Type II error while he knew the value of $\mu$.

Comment: I think you have "known" and "unknown" interchanged. If you saw it stated that way in print, can you ask whoever wrote it?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I did it a few hours ago, I forgot to edit the post. You were right, they were in fact interchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the population SD $\sigma$ is unknown, and hence estimated by
the population SD $S,$ then the appropriate test statistic is
$T = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}}.$ Under the null hypothesis
$H_0: \mu = \mu_0,$ the test statistic is distributed as Student's
distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

You can use printed
tables or software to find the critical value $t^*.$ Because this
is a right-tailed test (against $H_a: \mu > \mu_0$), you would
choose $t^*$ that cuts 5% from the upper tail of the distribution,
and reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance when $T > t^*.$  For example if $n = 16$ then $t^* = 1.731$ is 
the critical value for a for a test at level 5%.

This is a standard 'one-sample t test'. It assumes that the population is
normal or nearly normal. As the sample size $n$ increases the assumption
of normality becomes somewhat less important. An alternative test due to Wilcoxon
for the population *median* does not require normal data, but works best
if the population distribution is roughly symmetrical and when there are
no tied values in the data. This nonparametric rank-based test is called
the 'Wilcoxon signed-rank test'. If neither of these tests is appropriate,
then one of several kinds of 'permutation test' might be used.

If you are in doubt whether the one-sample t test is appropriate for your
data, then perhaps you can post your data or a histogram of it, and one
of us can help you decide.

Your use of "$P_{H_0}(R)+P_{H_1}(R^c)$" (the sum of type one and type two errors) is premature. First, we need to make sure what kind of test is to be
used. In practice, even if we know it is a one-sample t-test, that would require
a guess at $\sigma$ and a knowledge of both the sample size and the
difference $\mu_0 - \mu_1$. Not to be snarky, but an infinite sample size
would drive both error probabilities to 0.

Terminology in 'single quotes' can be found in most basic statistics texts,
and some online accounts are authoritative.

Comment: "Your use of " $P_{H_0}(R)+P_{H_1}(R^c)$ " (the sum of type one and type two errors) is premature. " That is how the problem was stated in my book

Comment: Without the context of the question from the book it is hard to guess what is really being asked. For _normal_ data, the t test has many optimal properties. For given $n, \mu_0, \mu_1,$ and $\alpha,$ it has minimal type II error.

Comment: In those cases you say there is a minimal type II error, but is there always a minimal type I error? In such case, wouldn't the minimal of the sum above be the just the sum of each minimal type error?